# Configuring same endpoint in controller and Spring integration configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have a rest controller with base path as /diagnosis with diff paths configured with diff methods like below.

- Post:  /diagnosis
- Get : /diagnosis/{diagnosisId}
- Put : /diagnosis
- delete: /diagnosis/{diagnosisId}

These end points are being consumed by two different systems. Now we are planing two implement spring integration so that we can produce two types of responses to two systems using routers and transformers. Now I am writing SI configuration and wanted to put the same end point for Post method /diagnosis in SI and remove the method level configuration in controller for Post. When I did that I am getting method not allowed exception.

Is it possible to configure this way? I wanted to put the same end point in SI and remove in controller because  I do not want to disturb the systems currently consuming this end point

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/diagnosissurvey")
public class DiagnosisSurveyServiceController {

    public ResponseForSfdcAndHybris saveDiagnosis(@RequestBody SurveyLevel submitRequest) {

    //some code here
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/questions/{categoryId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseObject getQuestions(@PathVariable String categoryId) throws JsonProcessingException {
    //some code here
    }

}
```

SI XML file:

```
 <int-http:inbound-gateway id="hybrisDiagnosisInboundGateway" 
      path="/diagnosissurvey" 
      supported-methods="POST"
      request-channel="hybrisDiagnosisInbound"
      reply-channel="diagnosisOutBoundToRouter"      
      request-payload-type="com.cardinalhealth.chh.model.SurveyLevel"  >
 </int-http:inbound-gateway>        

 <int:service-activator ref="diagnosisSurveyServiceController" method="saveDiagnosis" input-channel="hybrisDiagnosisInbound" output-channel="diagnosisOutBoundToRouter"/>
```

*Updated

Comment: Can you post the code which throws the exception?

Comment: @javaguy Hi I have updated the code and XML configuration. Pls suggest me solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing; your controller has a GET method with a sub-path; your SI XML has only a POST method at the root path. Exactly what URL you are hitting and which method?

Comment: I am hitting /diagnosissurvey which is in SI with Post method